# Lua class objects?

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm new to Lua and I'm wondering if there's a way to make many class objects to make different items in my case like in a OOP language like C# or Java. An example of what I'm saying is a class like this in Lua...

```
weapon = {}

function weapon.load()
{
    weapon.name = "CHASE'S BUG"
    weapon.damage = 1
    weapon.rare = "Diet Valley Cheez"
    weapon.hottexture = love.graphics.newImage("/ledata/invalid.png")
    weapong.playtexture = love.graphics.newImage("/ledata/invalid.png")
    weapon.dura = 1
    weapon.type = "swing"
}
```

But in a main class you could make new objects of that class which would be done like so in something like C#

```
weapon Dagger = new weapon();
Dagger.name = "Dagger of Some Mountain"
...
```

Is there a way to do that in Lua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua is object oriented, but it's not like Java/C++/C#/Ruby, etc, there's no native **class**, the only way to create new object is to clone an existing object. That's why it's called [prototype language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming)(like JavaScript).

Read [Programming in Lua Chapter 16](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html). You can mock normal OOP using metatable.

Comment: @freemann098 Yes, you can, Lua provides the tool to make tools, you need some work though. Read the book, that's the book every Lua programmer should read.

Comment: I would suggest also [MiddleClass](https://github.com/kikito/middleclass): it's a library implementing Object-Orientation for Lua.

Answer (score 2):

There're many ways. This is a simple one. Not really much OOP, you don't have inheritance and some other stuff. But I think this will work in your case.

```
function weaponFire ()
    print "BANG BANG"
end

function newWeapon (opts)
    local weaponInstance = {}

    weaponInstance.name = opts.name
    weaponInstance.damage = opts.damage

    weapon.fire = weaponFire

    return weaponInstance
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go about it is to use a table like so (using the example of a car):

```
    Car = {}
    Car.new = function(miles,gas,health)
        local self = {}

        self.miles = miles or 0
        self.gas = gas or 0
        self.health = health or 100

        self.repair = function(amt)
            self.health = self.health + amt
            if self.health > 100 then self.health = 100 end
        end

        self.damage = function(amt)
            self.health = self.health - amt
            if self.health < 0 then self.health = 0 end
        end

        return self
    end
```

It creates a table called 'Car' which would be the equivalent of a class, not an instance, then it defines a method "new" in the Car class which returns an instance of a car with variables and functions. An example to using this implementation:

```
    local myCar = Car.new()
    print(myCar.health)
    myCar.damage(148)
    print(myCar.health)
    myCar.repair(42)
    print(myCar.health)
```

Answer (score 0):

since you tagged with love2d, you may have a look at [middleclass](https://github.com/kikito/middleclass). It have [docs](https://github.com/kikito/middleclass/wiki) there. And more it have addon like [stateful](http://github.com/kikito/stateful.lua) which is mainly for game and love2d.